# How to add a form load event (currently not working)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms form where I am trying to show a user control when the form loads. Unfortunately, it is not showing anything. What am I doing wrong?  Please see the code below:

```
AdministrationView wel = new AdministrationView();
public ProgramViwer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}


private void ProgramViwer_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    formPanel.Controls.Clear();
    formPanel.Controls.Add(wel);
}
```

Please note I added the load event based on what I read in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Three ways you can do this - from the form designer, select the form, and where you normally see the list of properties, just above it there should be a little lightning symbol - this shows you all the events of the form. Find the form load event in the list, and you should be able to pick `ProgramViwer_Load` from the dropdown.

A second way to do it is programmatically - somewhere (constructor maybe) you'd need to add it, something like: `ProgramViwer.Load += new EventHandler(ProgramViwer_Load);`

A third way using the designer (probably the quickest) - when you create a new form, double click on the middle of it on it in design mode. It'll create a Form load event for you, hook it in, and take you to the event handler code. Then you can just add your two lines and you're good to go!

Comment: For some reason there is no dropdown options under load, in the events explorer.

Comment: @DaveKelly the dropdown will list all compatible event handlers you've already written - I suspect you just haven't created one yet. In this question the OP had already written one. Either copy and paste and modify the one in this question, or create one yourself.

Comment: can I skip this function?  I don't have it in my other winform application and the form just appears on the screen when I run it.

Answer (score 19):

You got half of the answer! Now that you created the event handler, you need to hook it to the form so that it actually gets called when the form is loading. You can achieve that by doing the following:

```
 public class ProgramViwer : Form{
  public ProgramViwer()
  {
       InitializeComponent();
       Load += new EventHandler(ProgramViwer_Load);
  }
  private void ProgramViwer_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
       formPanel.Controls.Clear();
       formPanel.Controls.Add(wel);
  }
}
```