# How to create a Sleep method for my application

Tags: c#, methods, wait

I want to create a method which makes my application wait X number of seconds, then continues on down a line of scripts. For example, this is the code that I have so far, after reading many similar help topics:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            methods.WriteTextToScreen(label1, "Hello!");
            methods.sleepFor(1);
            methods.WriteTextToScreen(label1, "Welcome!");
            methods.sleepFor(1);
            methods.WriteTextToScreen(label1, "Allo!");
        }

        public class methods
        {
            public static int timeSlept;

            public static void WriteTextToScreen(Label LabelName, string text)
            {

                LabelName.Text = text;
            }


            public static void sleepFor(int seconds)
            {
                timeSlept = 0;

                System.Timers.Timer newTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                newTimer.Interval = 1000;
                newTimer.AutoReset = true;

                newTimer.Elapsed += new     System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(newTimer_Elapsed);

            newTimer.Start();

            while (timeSlept < seconds)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            Application.DoEvents();

        }

        public static void newTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timeSlept = IncreaseTimerValues(ref timeSlept);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        public static int IncreaseTimerValues(ref int x)
        {
            int returnThis = x + 1;
            return returnThis;
        }

    }

}
}
```

What I want to do is have my program do the methods.WriteTextToScreen(label1, "Hello!")
then wait for 1 second, then continue on in the same fashion. The problem is that the Form I'm displaying the text on doesn't show up at all until it has written "Allo!" onto the screen, so the first time it appears it already says that. Am I doing something wrong, or is there just no way to do this?

Comment: Oh, god, not Application.DoEvents(). It just wont die!!!

Comment: Actually this [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) ref is more up to date. Also you don't need to put languages in your titles, that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form doesn't show until it has been constructed i.e. all the code in Form1 is run. See here for info on form constructors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.form.aspx

To fix your problem you could move the writeTextToScreen and sleep code into the forms on load method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx

Comment: So I need to override the OnLoad method, right? I've tried to do that, but where do I need to put that method to make the Form recognize that its been changed?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847376/how-to-add-a-form-load-event-current-not-working

Comment: The post you gave me was helpful, I realized that I needed to use the Form1.Shown event instead of Form1.Load to make sure that the Form was being displayed before I began doing stuff. It works fine now, thanks for the help!