# winforms, sending object from one window to another and print simple property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms. MainForm and BookDetailsForm.

From MainForm I'm sending object to the BookDetailsForm where I want to print simple book title on the form using label property.

```
Book book = repository.GetBook(1);
var formDetails = new BookDetailsForm(book);
formDetails.ShowDialog();
```

on BookDetailsForm.cs I have

```
private Book _book;

        public BookDetailsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public BookDetailsForm(Book book)
            : base()
        {           
            _book = book;

        }

        private void BookDetailsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = _book.Title;
        }
```

when debugging book object is succ. sent to the second constructor but BookDetailsForm_Load is never hit, so window is shown empty without populating label property.

Comment: Did you attach your Form_Load event in designer or anywhere else ?

Comment: does double click on the form attach Load event properly or should I need to do something else?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847376/how-to-add-a-form-load-event-current-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the base constructor, bypassing the call to `InitializeComponents()` where the event is wired up.

Call the no-parameter constructor by using this() instead of base():

```
public BookDetailsForm(Book book)
            : this()
        {           
            _book = book;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

put a break point in your load event if  does not hit the breakpoint 
 try to  clean your solution   menu build-> clean solution and recompile it
 sometimes the pdb symbols are not updated

Answer (score 0):

```
    public BookDetailsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public BookDetailsForm(Book book)
        : base()
    {           
        // add the init here
        _book = book;
        InitializeComponent();
        // map the book to the view
        // example:
        lblName.Text = _book.Title;
    }

    private void BookDetailsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = _book.Title;
    }
```