# How to run a method in main loop of windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, methods

i want to know the absolut best/easiest way to run a method in the main loop in of my windows forms program. can't find anything that really fits my needs efter locking for some days now. i'm really kinda new to programing and just started to learn windows forms.
so what is the best/easiest way to do it.

(the method is to look if a txt files exists in a folder, and then take the content of it, save it in a string, that is going to be displayed in a text box)
what it to load 3-4 times a sec, all the time even when its minimized.
I tried placing it / adding it to both form.load and application.idle - but form.load only does it ones every time the application starts, and application.idle only executes when I'm interacting with the program, but I want so that it will run even when the program is minimized.
(i have another program that is makeing the text file and i going to run att the same time as this program)

Comment: Do you think anyone will understand your *needs* here?? where and why you want the loop?

Comment: THis is the default already.

Comment: What loop? Where? How often it should execute? what kind of code it will execute?

Comment: execite 3-4 times a sec, all the time even when the application is minimized , and the code is to look for a txt file and take the content of it, then delete it.( i have an other program that mekes the text file, both aplickations i supooust to run at the same time)

Answer (score 1):

> the method is to look if a txt files exists in a folder, and then take the content of it, save it in a string, that is going to be displayed in a text box

You can use the [`Form.Load()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: Thx :D but how do i do that ? (not even haf a year sens i started my programing classes)

Comment: See [How to add a form load event (current not working)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847376/how-to-add-a-form-load-event-current-not-working).

Comment: work but not the way it was atended to be :/ i want it to try and load all the time, and when i just Form.Load() it just loaded ones ever time it started up, soo  i tryed with aplication.idel() but then it only loads when it loads when i interact whit it, and i want it to be able to be minimized and still run

Comment: A dumb way of doing this is to use a timer and hook up the Tick event, and call your method to look for the text file.  Are you trying to load outside changes made to the text file during runtime?

Comment: jupe i'm allready done a another program thats going to run at the same time and that is makeing the txt file