# C# - Method is not being called upon .Load or .Shown

Tags: c#, methods, load, call

I have a method that fills a listbox with information that is read from .txt file (first it is stored in an arraylist and then a list of arraylists is being displayed in the listbox).

The problem is that currently it works when I press a button "Load" but I need this method to be called once the program starts running. I tried using `.Load()` and `.Shown()` events but nothing happens then!

Two identical method calls in the main form, but only `button_click` works. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void frmMainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //READS EVENTS FROM THE INPUT FILE
    Services.readEvents(inputDataFile, AllExistingEvents);
    //DISPLAYS THEM IN THE EVENT LIST BOX
    Services.DisplayOnlyEvents(lstEvents);
}

private void btnReadInputFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //READS EVENTS FROM THE INPUT FILE
    Services.readEvents(inputDataFile, AllExistingEvents);
    //DISPLAYS THEM IN THE EVENT LIST BOX
    Services.DisplayOnlyEvents(lstEvents);
}
```

Comment: This code just doesn't belong in either event handler, it belongs in the constructor.  Best to spend some time to learn how writing event handlers and debugging your program works.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I needed to do this. Everything works brilliantly. Solution used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847376/how-to-add-a-form-load-event-current-not-working