# Trouble Creating Folder in AppData in a C# Project

Tags: c#

This is a simple enough topic I realize, but I cannot create a folder in the app I am working on.  I'm having trouble diagnosing the problem.  The app runs fine with the code, but the file and folder are not created.  The location of the folder and settings file will be in AppData\Roaming.  Here is the code I am using, which I believe is correct:

```
    private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path + "\\TestFolder"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\TestFolder");
        if (!File.Exists(path + "\\TestFolder\\settings.xml"))
            File.Create(path + "\\TestFolder\\settings.xml");
    }
```

The thing that is bothering me the most is that I have tried several ways to do this that I found in several thread posts here on SO.  None of them break the app as expected, but nothing happens.  It's as though the code is being completely skipped over or ignored.  I have introduced System.IO into the namespace if anyone is wondering.  The app is a WinForms app.

I'm a complete noob with C# and basically programming in general, but this seems so simple to do.  Many thanks for any help...

EDIT:  Here is the first part of the code.  This directly precedes the above in the Form.cs (TestForm.cs) file.  Maybe it will help:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Comment: Ensure the event handler is being called. Set a breakpoint on the first line and run your app in debug mode. Maybe the event handler is not attached to TestForm?

Comment: Apologies, trying to add some code here...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9847686/1260204. You probably did not subscribe to the OnLoad event.

Comment: The thing is that Visual Studio generates a designer partial of your Form class - TestForm.Designer.cs - in order to store the boilerplate code. That's why you don't see the code where the Load event is being subscribed by your form. Could you check if your handler is being called, doing what I said in my previous comment? The code you're showing is correct.

Comment: See my answer below. Add `Load += new EventHandler(TestForm_Load);` below `InitializeComponent();`.

Comment: Updated my original post with the first portion of the code in the form file TestForm.cs.  Maybe this will help?  Should I see something in Designer.cs?  I can post the code there if necessary, but I'm not sure what I am looking at.  I am looking over the info on the handler to attempt to piece together what might be missing...

Answer (score 1):

If it is never being hit you are missing the the line that subscribes to the event.

```
Load += new EventHandler(TestForm_Load);
```

You can also subscribe to the load event in the form designer. Use F4 to see the properties dialog, click on the form title bar, and then navigate to the events in the properties (lightning bolt). The name of the event is `Load`.

[image: Properties Dialog]

---

You probably did not subscribe to the form's load event. Assuming the class name is TestForm it should be similar to this, attaching to the event is the 2nd loc in the constructor.

```
public partial class TestForm : Form {

    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += new EventHandler(TestForm_Load); // !!  Add this line  !!
    }

    private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path + "\\TestFolder"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\TestFolder");
        if (!File.Exists(path + "\\TestFolder\\settings.xml"))
            File.Create(path + "\\TestFolder\\settings.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou.  This is exactly what was missing.  It's all so clear to me now lol... :)

Comment: @BoMcCullough - Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)).

Answer (score 0):

just a note on coding style - I switched to using the `Path.Combine` method for constructing "safe" paths. Like so:

```
private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string directory = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData, "TestFolder");
    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

    string file = Path.Combine(directory, "settings.xml");
    if (!File.Exists(file))
        File.Create(file);
}
```

Thanks, and I hope I got that right...