# Text file not being created on app start

Tags: c#

For some reason, when I start my application, it doesn't create a new file. Here is the code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!File.Exists("database.txt"))
        {
            File.Create("database.txt");
        }
        else if (File.Exists("database.txt"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database has been found, please go ahead and make your changes.");
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SubmitToDatabase std = new SubmitToDatabase();
        std.Show();
    }

    private void Search_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchDatabase sd = new SearchDatabase();
        sd.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the current directory? Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() Maybe it is being created, just not where you want it?

Comment: I changed the code to the constructor and it worked - is there something wrong by using "Form1_Load"? It doesn't seem to work. I want to do this when the application starts up.

Comment: You aren't supposed to use `File.Create` like that. Maybe you can try `File.WriteAllText("database.txt", "")` if you want to create an empty file?

Answer (score 1):

You may have not subscribed for Form1.Load event, it would explain why your method isn't called. [See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847376/how-to-add-a-form-load-event-currently-not-working) on different ways to hook up to form events, or simply write `form1.Load += Form1_Load;` somewhere in your code, ie. in constructor.